# Using .map and getting Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `to` is marked as required in `Link`, but its value is `undefined`

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jsx, react-router-dom

I'm getting this warning when I open my navbar
Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `to` is marked as required in `Link`, but its value is `undefined`.

I am using material-ui for this project
I am using a .map to create the different links

```
{menuItems.map((lsItem, key) => (
    <ListItem button key={key} component={Link} to={menuItems.listPath}>
       <ListItemIcon className={classes.listItem}>
          {lsItem.listIcon}
       </ListItemIcon>
       <ListItemText primary={lsItem.listText} className={classes.listItem} />
    </ListItem>
))};
```

Here is where they are being pulled from

```
const menuItems = [
    {
        listIcon: <Home />,
        listText: 'Home',
        listPath: '/'
    },
    ...
];
```

If I hard code the links I don't get a warning.
I am including `to={...}` and can't figure out why I am getting this warning, Thank you for any input!

Answer (score 1):

Change `to={menuItems.listPath}` to `to={lsItem.listPath}`:

```
                {menuItems.map((lsItem, key) => (
                    <ListItem button key={key} component={Link} to={lsItem.listPath}>
                        <ListItemIcon className={classes.listItem}>
                            {lsItem.listIcon}
                        </ListItemIcon>
                        <ListItemText primary={lsItem.listText} className={classes.listItem} />
                    </ListItem>
                ))};
```